# BLE Android API - onCharacteristicChanged is not getting called for every change in remote device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

This is what I am trying to achieve.

I have a BLE peripheral device which updates the Characteristic every 10ms with the ASCII values (0-255). I want to capture this values in my Android application. I am able to connect the device successfully and registered the the app for notifications from the device.

In the onCharacteristicChanged() method, I doing nothing but log the value from the characteristic. But what I found is that, the function is not getting invoked for every change. The ASCII values are getting skipped.

Is this because the high update frequency of the device? Does anyone else here experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're being a little optimistic with the update every 10ms, unless you have got your peripheral to renegotiate the connection interval. From what I have learned the connection interval for Android is around 48.5ms consequently your characteristic update needs to be a multiple of the connection interval. Get it going at a second then work your way down.

Answer (score 0):

Are notification updates meant to be guaranteed delivery type things? I don't know myself but if the answer is no then you should expect gaps.

Comment: Guaranteed delivery is indications, not notifications. Indications are acknowledged by receiving end.